# Sonata Admin Bundle listbox sort order

Tags: php, symfony

I have 2 entities one referenced to another with many to one relation. For example, User and City. 
 I need listbox with Cities in User edit page to be sorted by Name, not by Id.

How can I do it?

Comment: Hello. Welcome to StackOverflow. You have to specify your question, to be propperly answered. Write plese more, add screens and your code. It will be better!

Answer (score 0):

In your Entity, you can specify the ordering .

Example :

```
<?php
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Group")
 * @OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
private $groups;
```